# About SQL Tables with attributes in common

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm thinking one question, and always happened in our daily development life.
For example, i have a table1 with 20 columns, and table2 with 30 columns, table 3 with 40 columns.but for table 1,2,3 , they has common 10 columns.

A few examples might put this in context.

A pet store has data about dogs, cats, goldfish, etc.  All pets have a name, a price, a date obtained, etc.  But each kind of pet has attributes that the other kind doesn't have.

A database about vehicles has data about autos, trucks (lorries), and motorcycles.  They  all have a Vehicle Identification Number,  A registration number, and a year of manufacture.  But they each have their own attributes as well.

A database about customers has data about companies that are customers, and individual persons that are customers.  They both have phone numbers, but they have different attributes as well.

So what's the resonable design for the DB structure.

A : create 3 tables with 20,30,40 columns?
B : create 3 table with 10,20,30 columns and another table with the 10 common columns?If i search one record, i need to join the common info from the common table

So how can I analysis this performance question? Don't know about the sql working principle, will do some investigation works for that. 
Anyone can share your ideas about the design and the different performance

Comment: You should ask your question about query performance on [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You should add index on columns where you would like to add conditions

Comment: This is too broad a question.  In a transactional situation it's probably better to normalise away the duplicate/redundant columns.  But not always, it depends on the reason the model has these three tables in the first place, perhaps there are different constraints in place.  In an analytical situation it may be better to keep them separate as a kind of caching, or it may be better to normalise them so all three data-sets can be in the same tables thus making the SQL significantly easier to write.  So, ***without context, It Depends...***

Comment: Also different RDBMSs have different tuning strategies.

Comment: Yes , it's a broad question, If it happens in MS SQL Server., and table 1,2,3 will be always be queried , updated, inserted.So split the common columns into one common table is a better design? or worst@MatBailie

Comment: This would make a good "canonical question" for literally hundreds of specific questions where the question wants to know about superclasses and subclasses, but doesn't know how to find them.  If the community decided to make this a canonical question,  I'm prepared to put some hard work into improving the quality of my response.  for example, eliminating the references to the three tags, and instead including directly the descriptions of the three design techniques.  A canonical question and answer would be great for the next batch of questions on this topic.

Comment: By specific questions I mean question about cats, dogs, goldfish, and pets.  Or about cars, trucks, motorcylces, and vehicles, or about students, instructors, and community members.  and on, and on, and on.  It's the same problem, over and over again.  A canonical answer would help most of the questioners.

Comment: There are a trillion duplicate questions like this. As with every question, please google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title.

Comment: @philipxy, the problem is that, in this context, most people don't recognize their question as a duplicate.  If their question is about a pet store that has cats, dogs, parakeets and goldfish,  and they run across a question that is about a college that has students, instructors, and staff,  they don't see that it's really the same pattern.

Comment: @WalterMitty What do you mean by "the problem"? I don't know what your point its since my comment to the asker says "with & without your specific strings/names/code". (And my comment on your meta post suggests a canonical question should have the many phrasings in bullets.) But now I read the asker's original version and it was re which of 2 schemas has better performance. (Without giving sufficient details.) They still should have googled re *that* and found hits. I happen to disagree with your edit but either question version has many hits & is a duplicate & should not be answered.

Comment: This question is under discussion a [Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360842/3404097).

Comment: We can continue the meta discussion in the meta area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem  surfaces over and over again in data modeling. It is called "generalization/specialization" in ER modeling, and "superclass/subclass" in object modeling.

An object modeler uses the inheritance features built into the object model to solve the problem quite easily. The subclasses simply extend the superclass.
The relational modeler is faced with a problem. how to design the tables so as to emulate the benefits that one would get from inheritance?  That is the question you raised.

The simplest technique is called single table inheritance. Data about all subclasses are grouped into a single table for the superclass. There is a column, object_type, that groups together all the objects of a single type. No object can belong to more than one type. If a column is irrelevant to one of the subclasses, it will be left NULL in the rows that pertain to that subclass.

This simple solution works well for the smaller and simpler cases. The presence of a lot of NULLs adds a tiny bit to storage overhead, and a little bit to retrieval overhead. The developer may have to learn SQL three-valued logic if boolean tests are done on nullable columns. This can be baffling at first, but one gets used to it.

There is another technique, called class table inheritance. In this design, there are separate tables for each of the specialized subclasses, in addition to a combined table for all of them. When you want all of the data about a specific kind of object, you join the general table with the appropriate specialized table. There are fewer NULLs in this design, but you do more joining.  This technique works better in the larger and more complex cases.

There is a third technique called shared primary key. This technique is often used in conjunction with class table inheritance. The specialized tables for the subclasses have, as their primary key, a copy of the primary key of the corresponding entry in the general  table. This id column can be declared to be both the primary key and a foreign key.

This involves a little extra programming when new objects are to be added, but it makes the joins simple, easy, and fast.

Superclasses and subclasses happen all the time in the real world. Make your design simple and sound.  Test your initial design for performance. Then tweak it if you need to.